# Finding every $(m,n)\ (m\gt n)\in \mathbb N$ such that $m\pm n$ are square numbers and $mn$ is a cubic number.

Tags: number-theory

**Question** : Find every $(m,n)\ (m\gt n)\in \mathbb N$ such that $m\pm n$ are square numbers and $mn$ is a cubic number.

**Example** : I've already found the followings:

$$m=12500a^6, n=10000a^6$$
where $a$ is a natural number.

We can easily show that these satisfy the conditions : 
$$m-n=(50a^3)^2, m+n=(150a^3)^2, mn=(500a^4)^3.$$

However, I can neither find the other solutions nor prove that there is no other solution.

**Motivation** : I've been interested in the following question :

Do there exist $(m,n)\ (m\gt n)\in \mathbb N$ such that each of $m-n, m+n, mn$ is a square number?

The answer is **No**.

**Proof** : Letting $m+n=a^2, m-n=b^2, mn=c^2$, we get
$$a^4-b^4=(2c)^2$$
because of $(m+n)^2-(m-n)^2=4mn$.

On the other hand, if $x^4-y^4=z^2$ has a solution, letting $m=2(x^2+y-2), n=2(x^2-y^2)$, we get
$$m+n=(2x)^2, m-n=(2y)^2, mn=(2z)^2.$$

By the way, since it is well known that $x^4-y^4=z^2$ doesn't have any solution, then we now know that the answer for the above question is no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$  r = 2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 13^2 \cdot t^6  $$

$$  m = 13 r^2, \; \; n = 12 r^2, \; \; m+n = 25 r^2 , \; \; m - n = r^2 $$

$$  r^4 =  2^4 \cdot 3^8 \cdot 13^8 \cdot t^{24}  $$

$$  mn = 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 13 \cdot r^4 = 2^6 \cdot 3^9 \cdot 13^9 \cdot t^{24}  $$

There are lots of these, and strongly related to Pythagorean triples. Begin with the fact that $m$ must be the sum of two squares, as $2m$ is. If there is just one reasonable expression for $2m = a^2 + b^2,$ which will be the case for $m$ prime and $m \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ then $2n = a^2 - b^2$ in just one interesting way. Then just multiply both by $r^2$ and decide what $r$ needs to be to end up with a cube.

So: $m=17, 2m = 34 = 5^2 + 3^2, 2n = 5^2 - 3^2 = 16, n=8. $  Then switch to $m=17 r^2, n = 8 r^2.$ As 8 is already a cube, we just need $17 r^4$ a cube, minimum is $r=17^2.$ Finally $r = 17^2 t^6.$ So $$ r = 17^2 t^6, \; \; m = 17 r^2, \; \; n = 8 r^2, \; \; r^4 = 17^8 t^{24}, \; \; mn = 17^9 2^3 t^{24} .   $$

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer.